# contact between surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $s_1(x,y)=(x,y,f_2(x,y))$ and  $s_2(x,y)=(x,y,f_2(x,y))$ be two regular surfaces. What is the definition of contact between these 2 surfaces? I read somewhere that the osculating spheres of a surface are the spheres with the highest contact order in a given point. Can someome give me an algebraic intuition of what that mean?
Also, can I find quadratic surfaces that also have a nice contact with the surface?

Comment: Yes, the osculating sphere has the same tangent plane as the surface at the point of contact (depending on definitions, that's the first order contact) and the same curvature (that's the second order contact). The best way to calculate is to work with one surface implicitly (given by $F=0$ with the point a regular point) and see to what order $F$ vanishes (at the point) when you evaluate at points of the other surface. Warm up for this with the contact of a line and a surface; then you can substitute a parametrization of the line into the defining function of the surface.

Comment: I removed the contact-geometry tag: It refers to the geometry of maximally nonintegrable hyperplane distributions and not to order of contact between objects.